# Filter out NULL fields returned in a objCom.CommandText

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Using the script below, I am able to list users in an OU as expected however the output lists everything including users that are missing data in the custom ipphone field. I need help to modify the code to NOT list a user with a missing extension number in the ipphone field. "This indicates a user has left the company and should not show up on the phone list"

```
<%@ Language=VBScript  %>
<% response.Buffer = True %>
<html><head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Directory</h1>
<%
' Define the AD OU that contains our users

usersOU = "LDAP://OU=IT,OU=Hollister,OU=Houston,OU=NFSmith,DC=nfsmith,DC=info"

' Make AD connection and run query
Set objCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objCon.provider ="ADsDSOObject"

objCon.Properties("User ID") = "domain\user"
objCon.Properties("Password") = "password"
objCon.Properties("Encrypt Password") = TRUE
objCon.open "Active Directory Provider"

Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCom.ActiveConnection = objCon
objCom.CommandText ="select givenName,sn,telephonenumber,ipphone FROM '"+ usersOU +"' where ipphone='*' ORDER by givenName"

Set objRS = objCom.Execute

' Loop over returned recordset and output HTML

Response.Write "<table>" + vbCrLf
Do While Not objRS.EOF Or objRS.BOF
    Response.Write "  <tr>"
    Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("givenName") + "</td>"
    Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("sn") + "</td>"

    Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("telephonenumber") + "</td>"
    Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("IPphone") + "</td>"

    Response.Write "</tr>" + vbCrLf
    objRS.MoveNext
    Response.Flush
Loop
Response.Write "</table>"
' Clean up
objRS.Close
objCon.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
Set objCon = Nothing
Set objCom = Nothing
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the value is `Null` before writing the output:

```
Do Until objRS.EOF
    If Not IsNull(objRS("ipPhone")) Then
        Response.Write "  <tr><td>" + objRS("givenName")
        Response.Write "</td><td>" + objRS("sn")
        Response.Write "</td><td>" + objRS("telephoneNumber")
        Response.Write "</td><td>" + objRS("ipPhone")
        Response.Write "</td></tr>" & vbCrLf
        Response.Flush
    End If

    objRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the NULL records at all, why don't you tell your SQL query to exclude them?

So where you have

```
objCom.CommandText ="select givenName,sn,telephonenumber,ipphone FROM '"+ _
   usersOU +"' where ipphone='*' ORDER by givenName"
```

add a condition:

```
objCom.CommandText = "SELECT givenName, sn, telephonenumber, ipphone FROM '" & _
    usersOU & "' WHERE ipphone = '*' AND ipphone IS NOT NULL ORDER BY givenName"
```

(I'm not sure what the purpose of `ipphone = '*'` is, but I don't work with Active Directory much.)

The other approach, i.e. testing for `IsNull(objRS("ipPhone"))` in your code, is useful if you want to do something else if the field is null — maybe add an "inactive" class, that sort of thing.